# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Zip code must be in 99999 or 99999-9999 format

Tags: validation

Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger AccountTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 70 with id 0037000000mooaeAAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Zip code must be in 99999 or 99999-9999 format.: [MailingPostalCode]: Class.AccountService.updateRelatedContacts: line 18, column 1

Answer (score 8):

Seems simple enough, you just need to break the error down into pieces.

> AccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 70 with id 0037000000mooaeAAA;

Someone or something tried to update a `Contact`. You were able to update the first 70 or 71 `Contacts`.

The default action for DML is to fail the entire set of records that were undergoing this particular DML action, and roll back to their previous state.

> first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,

This error was caused by a validation rule added by a user (or possibly by someone using the `addError()` method in a trigger)

> Zip code must be in 99999 or 99999-9999 format.: [MailingPostalCode]:

The field that is being complained about is the standard `MailingPostalCode` field (presumably on `Contact`), and the data contained in this field does not satisfy the validation rule

> Class.AccountService.updateRelatedContacts: line 18, column 1

The error is happening in the `AccountService` class, in the `updateRelatedContacts` method on the specified line (this is likely just where the DML update is located)

If I had to guess at what's going wrong, your code is probably not quite robust enough and you're likely trying to update the `MailingPostalCode` for this particular `Contact` to null. That, or you're working with a `Contact` who is not based in the US or Mexico (Mexico's postal codes also happen to be 5 digits). The postal code format for Canada, for example, is "A1A 1A1"

Answer (score 3):

It means there is a custom validation rule on the Account object which is stopping your DML statement as the record you're updating does not meet the criteria.

Take a look at the validation rule and either edit it to allow the record you're updating or update your code so that it passes the validation rule criteria.